# Rename columns and merge with other sheet, by column name

Tags: excel, vba

I have two similar datasets/ranges, on separate sheets, both beginning in cell A1.The two sheets are named "table 1" and "table 2".

The first table, on sheetname:table1 is as follows:
[TABLE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12SmV.png)

The second table on sheetname:table 2 is as follows:
[TABLE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egupL.png)

The columns in the tables represent the same things, however are not identically named, or in the same order.

I'm trying to match the columns based on name ("school name" = "school address", "chalk" = "chalk box", "duster"="erasor", "board"="blackboard", "ruler" = "measuring stick").

I need to merge the second table into the first table, keeping the first table's column titles. I also need it to work if there are blanks in the data.

The end product (on a new sheet, or on Table1) should look like: [Final Product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUY2r.png)

I'm so sorry, I'm new to VBA. I can use

`Sheets("TABLE2").Range("A1:E5").Copy Destination:=Sheets("TABLE1").Range("D1")`

to copy my mock table across, however this does not perform the match, and does not work if there are additional rows.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you always matching columns rather than rows? Perhaps you could sort the columns and then copy across wholesale. Or use match to find the heading in row 1 and copy across that way.

Comment: Or perhaps just use lookup formulas.

Comment: There's around fifty columns in the real sheet I need to do it for, and the original sheet needs to be in the original order, so even if I renamed the columns and sorted from left to right, would I be able to put the data back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please. It will match the headers equivalence (stored in `arrEch`) and copy each column at a time, at once:

```
Sub testMatchTables()
  Dim shT1 As Worksheet, shT2 As Worksheet, lastR1 As Long, lastR2 As Long
  Dim arrEch As Variant, arrInt As Variant, El As Variant, matchRng1 As Range, matchRng2 As Range

    Set shT1 = Worksheets("TABLE1")
    Set shT2 = Worksheets("TABLE2")
     lastR1 = shT1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
     lastR2 = shT2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
     arrEch = Split("school name|school address,chalk|chalk box,duster|erasor,board|blackboard,ruler|measuring stick", ",")
     'Check the headers equivalence (for spelling errors):
     If Not ChechEquivalence(arrEch, shT1, shT2) Then Exit Sub
     For Each El In arrEch
        arrInt = Split(El, "|") 'extract each header from the "|" separated array element
        Set matchRng1 = shT1.Rows(1).Find(arrInt(0))
        Set matchRng2 = shT2.Rows(1).Find(arrInt(1))
        If Not matchRng1 Is Nothing And Not matchRng2 Is Nothing Then
            shT1.Cells(lastR1 + 1, matchRng1.Column).Resize(lastR2 - 1, 1).Value = _
                    shT2.Range(matchRng2.Offset(1), shT2.Cells(lastR2, matchRng2.Column)).Value
        End If
     Next
End Sub
'The next function check the matching headers equivalence:
Private Function ChechEquivalence(arr As Variant, shT1 As Worksheet, shT2 As Worksheet) As Boolean
   Dim El As Variant, arrInt As Variant, matchRng1 As Range, matchRng2 As Range
   For Each El In arr
        arrInt = Split(El, "|")
        Set matchRng1 = shT1.Rows(1).Find(arrInt(0))
        Set matchRng2 = shT2.Rows(1).Find(arrInt(1))
        If matchRng1 Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Eny equivalence between """ & arrInt(0) & """ could be find in """ & shT1.Name & """ header!" & vbCrLf & _
                "Please, check the array definition of this element, correct it and try again.", vbInformation, "Wrong Header spellinig"
            ChechEquivalence = False: Exit Function
        If matchRng2 Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Eny equivalence between """ & arrInt(1) & """ could be find in """ & shT2.Name & """ header!" & vbCrLf & _
                "Please, check the array definition of this element, correct it and try again.", vbInformation, "Wrong Header spellinig"
            ChechEquivalence = False: Exit Function
        End If
     Next
     ChechEquivalence = True
End Function
```

The way of equivalence check allows small differences between the array headers equivalence definition and the real headers spelling. I mean that 'rulers`will be find (instead of`ruler`) and the code will run well also in such a circumstance...

Comment: Thanks for this - I have run the first function and it works perfectly. I made some slight changes to the names and it still works.

I have not yet tried the second function, is the purpose of that to provide a warning if the column names do not match with the coded names?

Comment: @Sean: You checked it, in fact... The main sub calls it in order to check the spelling. Like I wrote, the code is able to match the headers if the string in the array exist inside the header string...